# Building RSS from other RSS feeds, how to prevent loop / recursion / circular inclusion?

Tags: php, recursion, rss, infinite-loop

This is an RSS feed (A) where the user can add several images, but he/she can also add a RSS feed (B) from a different user with images. When requesting feed (A), the server then fetches feed (B), and the images from the feed are then added to the requested feed (A).

What are some mechanisms or options to prevent infinite circular recursion?
e.g. when feed (B) also includes feed (A)

```
// Feed A setup
// - image1a
// - image2a
// - feed-B

// Feed B setup
// - image1b
// - feed-A

// fetching / assembling feed A
// - image1a
// - image2a
// - (A fetches feed-B)
// - image1b
// - (B fetches feed-A)
// - image1a
// - image2a
// - (fetched A fetches feed-B again)
// - image1b
// - (second B fetches feed-A again)
// .. recursion
```

Comment: Can you show your code for further reference? So that we all can get idea what you're doing?

Comment: the pseudo code is more or less, foreach($items); if($feed) simplexml_load_file($feed); addfeedimages(); - I'm starting to think along the lines of adding a unique feed_id to the individual images, so that if feed A encounters one of its own feed_id in the images from  an external feed, then recursion is probably occurring. This might work if the feed-player can ignore these extra feed_id nodes on the RSS XML items. However! if the recursion occurs between feed (B) and feed (C) then feed (A) will not know.

Comment: Without sample code it's hard to write entire code for your query. You have to show some code work. Then we can help.

Answer (score 1):

There are three solutions:

- Store the original feed id with each item and forward only items created initially for each feed,
- or forward all items for each feed, and pass around a list of all feeds the item has been in (and check that list),
- or use a unique itemID for each RSS, store it only once, put a unique constraint or primary key on the itemID, and thus never store an item twice for each feed.

Comment: thanks for your answer. the problem was that when assembling the feed, external feeds are fetched. There is no way to prevent the other feed from fetching this feed, therefore i used a file lock. I played with adding my own feed-id, but ended up with relying on the guid. If the other feed can have an identical image (same guid from sha1), so i added a unique id to the guid as well.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, the solution is in several stages.

**1 locking** : On request return a copy of the cached XML. During building the feed XML, set a lock. This prevents external feeds that are fetching this feed, from triggering a second new build. The external feed will only receive the cached XML.

**2 identify items** : The lock stops a potential runaway process, but the feed XML does grow on every request with the previously cached XML items. To prevent duplicates add a unique identifier for the feed to each "guid" field. If an item is the feeds own, don't include it and log a message (and notify if needed).